# How to store an image in Redis using Erlang

Tags: erlang, redis

I need to store the conversation between `A, B User`. And the user can **share** their **image** in their **conversation**. And how to store the `Message` data as well as the `image` in `Redis`. I am using the **eredis client** for my **Erlang** application. For the message string, Shall I use `LIST command` in redis? otherwise Is any other command is better than LIST for it. Does the redis support storing of an image by using Erlang? If it possible means how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Redis is binary-safe so you can store the image directly in it.

Use [`file:read_file/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html#read_file-1) to read the image in Erlang.

Comment: thanks for your response.. And how can i use it in Erlang.. I refer base64 for erlang in http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/base64.html And in this link Data refer the variable. How can i assign it in my image?

Comment: @No_Rulz Updated my answer with a different approach.